# Storm Tick Tuple from a spout

Tags: apache-storm

I want to configure my spout to emit tick tuples on 2 different frequencies on different streams. My questions are as follows:

1. I understand how this is done using the bolt. But, on a spout, will the tick tuple invoke the next Tuple method on every tick?
2. How can I determine the frequency at which the tick was invoked? Meaning, the actual value of the time I configured in the config object?

Comment: I don't understand how it is different from configuring it using usual bolt way ? In a bolt it can be checked using this function 
`private static boolean isTickTuple(Tuple tuple) {
       return tuple.getSourceComponent().equals(Constants.SYSTEM_COMPONENT_ID)     && tuple.getSourceStreamId().equals(Constants.SYSTEM_TICK_STREAM_ID);
  }`

Comment: Why not using 2 spouts or 1 spout + 1 bolt with tick tuples? Do you really need merged data in your single spout? Beware of complexity if you mix too much data, if you can isolate in 2 components it would definitely be the best option.

Answer (score 3):

Only bolts can receive tick tuples. Spouts can only *emit* tuples.

I'm assuming you're trying to do a "read" every so often from within your spout in order to emit a new tuple.

For example, to sleep 50 milliseconds between reads:

```
@Override
public void nextTuple() {
   try {
      String message = _mqClient.getMessage();
      if (message != null) {
         _collector.emit(new Values(message));
      } 
      // sleep for 50 milliseconds
      Utils.sleep(50);
   } catch (Exception e) {
      _collector.reportError(e);
      LOG.error("MQ spout error {}", e);
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this can help you:

https://github.com/ptgoetz/storm-signals

> Storm-Signals aims to provide a way to send messages ("signals") to
>   components (spouts/bolts) in a storm topology that are otherwise not
>   addressable.
>
> Storm topologies can be considered static in that modifications to a
>   topology's behavior require redeployment. Storm-Signals provides a
>   simple way to modify a topology's behavior at runtime, without
>   redeployment.

Comment: Storm signals is no longer maintained.